# Commutative monoid proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary-operations

Consider the algebraic structure $(Z × Z, ⊥)$, with $(a, b) ⊥ (c, d) = (a + c, bd)$ for each $a$, $b$, $c$, $d ∈ Z$.

> Prove that $(Z × Z, ⊥)$ is a commutative monoid

My attempt:

Addition $(a+c)$ and multiplication $(bd)$ are commutative operations in the set of integer numbers, so $(Z × Z, ⊥)$ is a commutative monoid.

Is my proof right?

Answer (score 1):

You proved correctly that $\perp$ is commutative. You must also provo that it is associative and that there is an identity in $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},\perp)$.

Comment: A monoid is said commutative if the operation is commutative. Why do I have to prove also that it's associative and that there is an identity?

Comment: @Rose Because you haven't proved yet (as far as I know) that $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},\perp)$ is a monoid.

Comment: How do I prove that the $(Z×Z,⊥)$ is associative?

Comment: @Rose Using the fact that $+$ and $\times$ are associative.

Comment: How do I find the neutral element?

Comment: Using the respective neutral elements of $+$ and $\times$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. How do I find them?

Comment: @Rose Think. What is the only $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that, for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$,$$(a,b)\perp(x,y)=(x,y)\perp(a,b)=(x,y)?$$

Comment: @Rose Do you know what a neutral element is?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, but I don't know how to find it

Comment: @Rose Well, (at the risk of repeating José's comment) do you know an element $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $a+x=x=x+a$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I don't know.

Comment: @Rose In your question, you wrote that, since addition and multiplication of integers are commutative operations, then $\perp$ is commutative too. How do you know that?

Comment: @Rose Then in fact you have no proof at all of the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},\perp)$ is commutative.